# How to hide the URL address which shows on the bottom of the papers when printing something from a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, hide

Is there away to make a web page print without showing the URL at the bottom of the printed pages? Or if possible to hide the page numbers which shows at the top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a browser setting, configurable from the browser (the specifics depend on *which* browser) and is not under the control of page authors.

Comment: Can I at least control which URL is being printed?

Comment: Only by providing that content the user wants to print on that URL and that URL only.

Comment: Not the url, but you can set the fragment identifier with __window.location.hash__.

Answer (score 2):

n general, the page elements for the headers and footers are controled by the browser (IE, Firefox, and Opera, for example, all display somewhat different information).

For browsing, you can turn this off in the Page Setup. Using Internet Explorer as an example, go to File > Page Setup and removing the tags in the Header and Footer boxes. This will provide a clean print of the page without the noted headers and footers.

Hope this helps!